# tensorflow transfer learning problems to run on GPU

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

I am trying to run the retrain.py script (available here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py). I have noticed that the part starting with the line 747 is executed on CPU when the default should be GPU. So, I have added the following line to force it to work on GPU:

```
`with tf.device("/gpu:0"): 
  (train_step, cross_entropy, bottleneck_input, ground_truth_input, final_tensor) = add_final_training_ops(len(image_lists.keys()),
                                      FLAGS.final_tensor_name,
                                      bottleneck_tensor)`
```

It causes the following error:

```
'tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'gradients/Mean_grad/Prod': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available
     [[Node: gradients/Mean_grad/Prod = Prod[T=DT_INT32, keep_dims=false, _device="/device:GPU:0"](gradients/Mean_grad/Shape_2, gradients/Mean_grad/range_1)]]
Caused by op u'gradients/Mean_grad/Prod', defined at:
File "retrain_tensorboard_pickle_mean.py", line 921, in <module>
tf.app.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
File "retrain_tensorboard_pickle_mean.py", line 839, in main
(train_step, cross_entropy, bottleneck_input, ground_truth_input, label_ground_truth_input, final_tensor) = add_final_training_ops(len(image_lists.keys()), FLAGS.final_tensor_name, bottleneck_tensor)
File "retrain_tensorboard_pickle_mean.py", line 686, in add_final_training_ops
cross_entropy_mean)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 190, in minimize
colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 241, in compute_gradients
colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 481, in gradients
in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py", line 91, in _MeanGrad
factor = (math_ops.reduce_prod(input_shape) //
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 810, in reduce_prod
keep_dims, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1115, in _prod
keep_dims=keep_dims, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2146, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1154, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

...which was originally created as op u'Mean', defined at:
File "retrain_tensorboard_pickle_mean.py", line 921, in <module>
tf.app.run()
[elided 1 identical lines from previous traceback]
File "retrain_tensorboard_pickle_mean.py", line 839, in main
(train_step, cross_entropy, bottleneck_input, ground_truth_input, label_ground_truth_input, final_tensor) = add_final_training_ops(len(image_lists.keys()), FLAGS.final_tensor_name, bottleneck_tensor)
File "retrain_tensorboard_pickle_mean.py", line 681, in add_final_training_ops
cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 783, in reduce_mean
keep_dims, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 973, in _mean
keep_dims=keep_dims, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2146, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1154, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

I have found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1140) that it might be a problem that mean is not implemented on GPU but on the other hand there is a [commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_mean.cc) on github which fixes counting mean on GPU.

Previous part, e.g. generating bottlenecks (line 744) runs perfectly on GPU, without even forcing it.

I would be grateful for any help!!

Justyna

Comment: Mean GPU implementation was added recently, maybe you are using older version?

Comment: Hmm, we have the master version from yesterday with all the commits concerning reduction_ops_mean. So, it's really weird... So you say, it should not provide any errors with the newest version of tensorflow?

I have also tried to replace usage of method reduce_mean with counting mean by hand so counting reduce_sum and dividing it by number of elements of tensor. This way there is no error when forcing work on GPU but I still see 0% usage of GPU.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried it, and seems like MeanGrad/Prod isn't getting placed on GPU for me either, looking

Comment: So Prod with integer inputs is not registered for GPU. Which seems like an omission because Prod with floating point inputs is registered. Filed an issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1919

Comment: ok, thanks for adding an issue on that!

Comment: nice catch anyway. Was an easy fix, should propagate to the code base in a day or 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been fixed in [b874e2c](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/b874e2ccfda77c964bfb0a41a8dc339e320b185c), nice catch